# Merge items of two lists into list of tuples that also contains index

Tags: python, list, tuples

What would be the most pythonic way of achieving the following:

```
list_a = ["A", "B", "C"]
list_b = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

idx_start = 100

result = [ (100, "A", "X"), (101, "B", "Y"), (102, "C", "Z") ]
```

The lists are guaranteed to be of the same size.

Comment: Would it be alright if your `result` was a dictionary with tuples for values? `result = {100:('A','X'), 101:('B','Y'),102:('C','Z')}`

Comment: Yes, that will do too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import count
zip(count(idx_start), list_a, list_b)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've been looking for - very elegant.

Comment: It works even when the two lists are not the same size. It stops as soon as the shortest list is exhausted.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a list comp

```
>>> list_a = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> list_b = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
>>> idx_start = 100
>>> [(idx_start+i,list_a[i],list_b[i]) for i in range(len(list_a))]
[(100, 'A', 'X'), (101, 'B', 'Y'), (102, 'C', 'Z')]
```

Other ways include

- `[(idx_start+i,list_a[i],list_b[i]) for i,v in enumerate(list_a)]`

Answer (score 2):

Zip is also an option

```
zip(range(idx_start,idx_start+len(list_a)), list_a, list_b)
```

Comment: I agree. I used zip too, but with a less subtle enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[(i + start, a, b) for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list_a, list_b))]
```

Comment: Alternatively, how about this variation? `[(i, a, b) for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list_a, list_b), idx_start)]` Might be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using HashSet.
What I did was instantiate a var inside a for loop adding index and both values inside the HashSet.
Something logic like that:

```
for (int i=0; i<a.length(); i++) {
   result.add(i,list_a[i],list_b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you accepted that your result can be a dictionary (or list) with tuples for values, try this:

```
>>> list_a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> list_b = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> idx_start = 100
>>>
>>> result_list = list(enumerate(zip(list_a, list_b), start=idx_start))
>>> result_dict = dict(enumerate(zip(list_a, list_b), start=idx_start))
>>>
>>> print (result_list)
[(100, ('A', 'X')), (101, ('B', 'Y')), (102, ('C', 'Z'))]
>>> print (result_dict)
{100: ('A', 'X'), 101: ('B', 'Y'), 102: ('C', 'Z')}
```